# wp-load.php not found - 404 - Buddypress & Ajax

Tags: ajax, buddypress

I'm having an issue with Buddypress ajax calls. The calls themselves are being made, however it's on the callback i'm having problems. I'm using a custom theme, with some custom pages for buddy press. All the same javascript files are loaded and the ajaxurl is defined as normal.

When i interact with anything in Buddpress (favourite, post message, comment etc) I get a 404 on wp-load.php in console. The content is there. The ajax function works itself as if you refresh the page the content is updated.

Tried a few things to fix up but getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After agonising on this for a while, there was a simple fix which i placed in the Ajax.php file.

`status_header( 200 );`